# PHP for each for items in array with Drupal

Tags: php, loops

I am trying to calculate a value based on a price field in an entity reference field.

I currently have this, which works...

```
if (isset($entity->field_choose_a_package['und'][0]['target_id'])) {
    $package1nid = $entity->field_choose_a_package['und'][0]['target_id'];
    $package1 = node_load($package1nid);
    $package1price = $package1->field_price['und'][0]['value'];
} else {
    $package1price = 0;
}

if (isset($entity->field_choose_a_package['und'][1]['target_id'])) {
    $package2nid = $entity->field_choose_a_package['und'][1]['target_id'];
    $package2 = node_load($package2nid);
    $package2price = $package2->field_price['und'][0]['value'];
} else {
    $package2price = 0;
}

if (isset($entity->field_choose_a_package['und'][2]['target_id'])) {
    $package3nid = $entity->field_choose_a_package['und'][2]['target_id'];
    $package3 = node_load($package3nid);
    $package3price = $package3->field_price['und'][0]['value'];
} else {
    $package3price = 0;
}

$packagestotal = $package1price + $package2price + $package3price;

$entity_field[0]['value'] = $packagestotal;
```

However, there could be an unlimited amount of packages added, and rather than me replicate the code for 20+ packages to try and cover my bases, there must be a way I can do a for each loop.

I have tried something like this,

```
$arr = $entity->field_choose_a_package['und'];

foreach ($arr as &$value) {
    if (isset($entity->field_choose_a_package['und'][$value]['target_id'])) {
        $package1nid = $entity->field_choose_a_package['und'][$value]['target_id'];
        $package1 = node_load($package1nid);
        $package1price = $package1->field_price['und'][$value]['value'];
    } else {
        $package1price = 0;
    }
}

unset($value);
```

but I cant figure out how to increment the variables, or if even need to? Can i just calculate the totals from the foreach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$packagestotal = 0;
$numPackages = 3;

for($i = 0; $i <= $numPackages; $i++) {
    if(isset($entity->field_choose_a_package['und'][$i]['target_id'])) {
      ${'package' . $i . 'nid'} = $entity->field_choose_a_package['und'][$i]['target_id'];
      ${'package' . $i} = node_load(${'package' . $i . 'nid'});
      $packagestotal += ${'package' . $i}->field_price['und'][0]['value'];
    }
}

$entity_field[0]['value'] = $packagestotal;
```

That should work.

Although, I would recommend that you wrap the package variables in an array rather than using [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php) as then the code would be much more readable and you could access each package attribute using `$package[$i]`

Comment: So the numPackages restricts the amount of rows? For example, I could set it to 100 to safely assume noone could order, (or afford) more than 100 packages?

Comment: Well $numPackages just says how many times the for loop should iterate. If $packages100 doesn't exist an error will be thrown. This code assumes you know ahead of time how many $package variables there are.